# F# JsonConverter seems to be ignored in .NET7

Tags: asp.net, serialization, f#, .net-7.0, discriminated-union

First of all, the problem appeared once we upgraded to .NET 7. With the previous versions, both 5 and 6 the attr worked as intended.

There is custom JSON converter:

```
type RouteCheckConverter() =
    inherit JsonConverter<RouteCheckResponse>()

    override _.Read(reader, _, _): RouteCheckResponse =
        match reader.GetInt32() with 
        | 200 -> RouteOk
        | 301 -> RouteRedirect
        | 404 -> RouteNotFound
        | _ -> failwithf "Unknown route check response"

    override _.Write (writer, r, _): unit =
        match r with
        | RouteOk -> writer.WriteNumberValue 200
        | RouteRedirect -> writer.WriteNumberValue 301
        | RouteNotFound -> writer.WriteNumberValue 404
```

RouteCheckResponse is discriminated union:

```
type RouteCheckResponse = | RouteOk | RouteRedirect | RouteNotFound
```

And here's the class using the converter:

```
type RouteCheckResultDTO = {
    page: ProductPageDTO option
    redirectTo: string option
    [<JsonConverter(typeof<RouteCheckConverter>)>] 
    response: RouteCheckResponse
}
```

However, when the app is trying to return the DTO I get this exception:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.NotSupportedException: F# discriminated union serialization is not supported. Consider authoring a custom converter for the type.
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.FSharpTypeConverterFactory.CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverterFactory.GetConverterInternal(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetConverterForType(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean resolveJsonConverterAttribute)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreateJsonTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
         at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoNoCaching(Type type)
         at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
         at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(Type type, Boolean ensureConfigured, Boolean resolveIfMutable)
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo.Configure()
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.InitializePropertyCache()
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.Configure()
         at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureLocked|143_0()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

etc, etc, which means the converter has no effect. I failed to find any possible reasons. Is it a bug, or should I add any kind of option/midlleware/registration code/wharever?

Comment: https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson

Comment: @BentTranberg according to the docs I'm supposed to use `JsonSerializer.Serialize` method explicitly. This is not what I'm trying to achieve, I only want the converter working again (and automatically serialize my DTOs in controllers), just like it worked in previous .NET versions.

Comment: Sorry, I understand too little of this, since I don't use System.Text.Json. Is the problem perhaps explained on this page about changes in System.Text.Json in .NET 7 ? : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/